# Decode q'C[[C' Kg S7S'OwVTS'S

Tags: cipher

This cipher is difficult, but breakable:

q'C[[C' Kg S7S'Ow**VT**S'S

Hint:

> The **VT** is one symbol...use this information how you may

Edit:

> Spaces represent spaces in the message, but other punctuation is part of the code

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please take the tour (you'll also get a badge too!) to better undestand our community's expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a simple substitution cipher for

> "Grammar is everywhere".

I think I was *supposed* to get it using

> ASCII codes somehow, considering that "vertical tab" is an ASCII character often represented by VT. But just decoding as a cryptogram works too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I forgot that this also works as a substitution cipher. Oh well. It is the ASCII binary codes backwards, in ASCII. But I forgot it was still a substitution cipher.